# Preimage of a prime ideal in a ring of formal power series.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, power-series, formal-power-series

Let $k = \overline{k}$ be a field. We have the inclusion $\iota:k[x,y] \to k[\![x,y]\!]$ and the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} = (y - \sum_{n\geq 1} x^n/n!)$. This ideal is prime, because it is the kernel of the surjective homomorphism, $\phi : k[\![x,y]\!] \to k[\![x]\!]$ defined by sending $x \mapsto x$ and $y \mapsto \sum_{n\geq 1} x^n/n!$. I want to show that $\iota^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}) = (0)$. For reference, this is II-3 (b) in *The Geometry of Schemes* by Eisenbud and Harris.

Here is my solution so far. Suppose $f \in k[x,y]$ so that $(\phi\circ\iota)(f) = 0$, i.e. 
$$0 = f\bigg(x, \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{x^n}{n!}\bigg).$$ 
Then, we must show that $f(x,y) = 0$. We can write $f(x,y) = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}x^iy^j$, where all but finitely many $a_{ij} = 0$, also suppose $deg(f) = d$. Using the fact that the exponential generating function of $(e^x - 1)^j/j! = \sum_{m=0}^\infty S(m,j)x^m/m!$, we get that
$$(\phi\circ\iota)(f) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}S(m,j)\frac{j!}{m!}x^{m+i}$$
where $S(m,j)$ are the Stirling numbers of the second kind. Note this power series is zero if and only if the coefficients of $x^n$ are zero for all $n\geq 0$; thus,
$$[x^n](\phi\circ\iota)(f) = \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^{n-i} a_{ij} S(n-i,j) \frac{j!}{(n-i)!} = 0.$$
Note that we are using the fact that $S(k,l) = 0$ if $k < l$. Now, for each $n$, we get a linear equation in the $a_{ij}$'s which only involve the coefficients so that $i + j \leq \text{min}(n,d)$. Almost surely, the only solution is the trivial one, because there are infinitely many equations and only $d(d+3)/2$ indeterminates; however, I am having trouble showing this. If you have any ideas on how to finish or maybe try a different approach, it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: If $f(x, e^x-1)=0$ for a non-zero polynomial $f(x,y)$, this says $e^x-1$ is algebraic, which is absurd (of course, the proof needs some work like yours).

Comment: I take it that $k$ has characteristic $0$?

Comment: Yes, it definitely does.

Comment: Also, the system of equations can be written as $Bx = 0$ where the columns are indexed by $(i,j)$ so that $i + j \leq d$ and $i,j\geq 0$, the rows are indexed by $\mathbb{N}_0$, and the entries are $B_{n,(i,j)} = S(n - i, j) \frac{j!}{(n-i)!}$

Comment: @Servaes Dividing by $n!$ should mean characteristic zero.